# *args and **kwargs Python

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

I'm working on an exercise, I tried to solve it, but no result, I had to look at the solution, in order to have an idea and repeat it, the problem, I am stuck, a little lost.

```
# Create an @authenticated decorator that only allows the function to run is user1 has 'valid' set to True:

 user1 = { 'name': 'Sorna',
           'valid': True }         #changing this will either run or not run the message_friends function.
```

Solution :

```
def authenticated(fn):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    if args[0]['valid']:
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper

@authenticated
def message_friends(user):
    print('message has been sent')

message_friends(user1)
```

I really don't get this part :

```
if args[0]['valid']:
```

My question is `if user1 = dict`, why can't i just use `**kwards` so i can just check if the value is True by calling only [valid]: 
where it comes from the `args[0]`?

Help, i'm really stuck with this..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: As it is, you're calling `message_friends(user1)`, which passes `user1` as a plain positional argument, so it will be in `args[0]`.  If you want to call a function and pass the contents of a dictionary as kwargs, use the `**` operator: `message_friends(**user1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorator can be written a bit more clearly to not use `args[0]`, does this help you understand?

```
def authenticated(fn):
    def wrapper(user, *args, **kwargs):
        if user['valid']:
            return fn(user, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@authenticated
def message_friends(user):
    print('message has been sent to', user['name'])

message_friends({'name': 'Sorna', 'valid': True})
message_friends({'name': 'Bob', 'valid': False})
```

Now `*args, **kwargs` is only there to pass along any other arguments the decorated function might have.

This is also more robust because it works whether `user` is passed positionally or as a keyword argument.

Comment: So by writing this args[0] i'm saying that i have 0 args so the programm will try to look in **kwargs ?

Comment: @Zeentanas no, args is a tuple of all positional arguments (except those already bound to other parameters, like `user` in this case) passed to the function, and args[0] is the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kwargs if you pass in `user1` as a **k**eyword-**arg**ument. For example, `message_friends(user_argument=user1)` would then have `args == []` and `kwargs == {'user_argument': user1}`

Further illustration of this point

```
def my_func(*args, **kwargs):
   print(f"Args: {args}")
   print(f"Kwargs: {kwargs}")

>> my_func(1, 2, 3, 4)
Args: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Kwargs: {}

>> my_func(1, 2, three=3, four=4)
Args: [1, 2]
Kwargs: {"three": 3, "four": 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@authenticated` decorator does the following:

1. Ensure that the function is called with at least one positional argument (else, an exception is raised).
2. Ensure that this first argument is a dictionary, or at least supports item access by string subscripts (again, otherwise an exception is raised).
3. Ensure that the key `'valid'` is found in the dictionary (else, exception).
4. If the key exists in the dictionary and has a **True** boolean value, then the original function is called and its return value returned by the decorated function. Else, no function is called, and no value returned.

It's not a very neat way of decorating functions, but if you can ensure that conditions 1 through 3 always hold, condition 4 can be useful in some scenarios.